# Query to sum some values of a column with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a table with this values:

```
name     | executing | failed |
-------------------------------
task1         0          1
task2         1          0
task3         1          0
task4         0          0
```

With a query i want to get:

- The total amount of `executing` task (2 in the example, `task2` and `task3`)
- The total amount of `failed` task (1 in the example, `task1`)
- The total amount of *pending task* (those that are `executing=0` and `failed=0`, 1 in the example, `task4`)

I can get the first two by uysing the following query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(executing), 0) Executing, IFNULL(SUM(failed), 0) Failed FROM mytable;
```

How can I expand my query so I can get another column with the sum of pending tasks?

Thanks in advance

Expected output:

```
executing | failed | pending
----------------------------
     2         1          1
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (Formatted text here too.)

Comment: @jarlh: desired output added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specify how you want the results.  I would do this as:

```
select (case when executing = 1 and failed = 0 then 'Executing'
             when failed = 1 then 'Failed'
             when executing = 0 and failed = 0 then 'Pending'
             else 'Unknown'
        end) as status, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by status;
```

You can also easily pivot the data using conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(executing = 1 and failed = 0) as Executing,
       sum(failed = 1) as Failed,
       sum(executing = 0 and failed = 0) as Pending
from t;
```

This uses a MySQL shorthand that treats boolean expressions as numbers -- with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(executing) AS Executing
    , SUM(failed) as Failed
    , SUM(CASE 
        WHEN executing = 0 AND failed = 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END
    ) AS Pending
FROM mytable;
```